# Javascript error on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on getting a slideshow mobile friendly, but am running into a problem. I'm pretty sure it's javascript related because pages without the slideshow load fine. The site has a lot of images all categorized in the NextGen Gallery plugin, so I installed a slideshow plugin that would work with the existing setup.

It works fine on desktop without any console errors, but when it's loaded on my phone I get an error stating, "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded." It tries a few more times, then gives up.

I've never run into this with anything I've ever made, so I'm not sure where to start to try and fix it since I don't have any errors to go off of. Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a similar plugin that can integrate with NextGen Gallery as well?

An example can be seen here: [example slideshow](http://gomolka-sub.ndmr.com/application-gallery/bath/)

Slideshow plugin: [NextGen Galleryview](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-galleryview2/)

Comment: Do you get the error if you emulate a mobile browser? Dev tools on most major browsers can do this.

Comment: You're probably using images that are too large for the limited memory of mobile browsers.

Comment: @VinnyM No, works fine.

Comment: @JeremyBanks ah, that is very possible. I'll look into it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I think that is exactly what it is. It looks like Safari can only handle between 8 and 10mb before it hangs or crashes. Thanks for giving me that idea.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped. I've run into this and similar issues when working with image galleries on mobile before. It's tricky how limits can vary between devices.